# automatizar "Recordar contraseña" con selenium y java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, test, chromedriver

recién comienzo en el mundo de la automatización y me gustaría poder probar un login que tiene la casilla "Recordar contraseña", el problema es que el navegador abre totalmente limpio (sin cookies) por lo que a pesar de ya tener una sesión iniciada de manera manual, siempre se abrirá una nueva ventana en el login, si alguien tiene un ejemplo, se lo agradecería, estoy usando chrome, selenium y java

Comment: Puedes guardar los datos en algún archivo.

Comment: Que datos, soy nuevo y no se de que datos hablas

Comment: De las cuentas. Querías tener algún modo de conservar los datos de login, o no?

Comment: no realmente, lo que necesito es poder probar la funcionalidad de la casilla "recordar contraseña", es decir, que al marcar la casilla, sin importar que cierre la pestaña, la sesión se mantenga, y al no tener marcada la casilla, que la sesión expire

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]